# Wrap inline ul next to each other with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Basically this is what I want:

[image]

I want the uls to wrap. I gave every list a width of 10rem to make them block elements, but I actually want the width to be the size of the li.

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

.design-list, .motion-list, .dev-list {
    width: 10rem;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Tools</h2>
      <div class="lists">
        <div class="design-list">
          <h3>Design</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Photoshop</li>
            <li>Illustrator</li>
            <li>XD</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="motion-list">
          <h3>Motion</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>After Effects</li>
            <li>Premiere Pro</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="dev-list">
          <h3>Front-End Development</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>HTML5</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>JQuery</li>
            <li>Bootstrap</li>
            <li>Java</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: also in css selector change `.list` to `.lists` then the flex properties will apply.

Comment: @AneesIjaz oh man thanks that was it. I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ul` and `li` have margin or padding, depending on the browser, by default. You need to override this default style within your menu:

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.lists {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
  }

.design-list, .motion-list, .dev-list {
    width: 10rem;
  }

ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tools</h2>
      <div class="lists">
        <div class="design-list">
          <h3>Design</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Photoshop</li>
            <li>Illustrator</li>
            <li>XD</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="motion-list">
          <h3>Motion</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>After Effects</li>
            <li>Premiere Pro</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="dev-list">
          <h3>Front-End Development</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>HTML5</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>JQuery</li>
            <li>Bootstrap</li>
            <li>Java</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```